# CakePHP change locale dynamically

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, locale, cakephp-3.x

I've my CakePHP app internationalized through `.po` files.

The file structure is as follows:

```
- src
   - Locale
      - en_EN
      - en_ES
```

The app is correctly translated at startup by:

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'en_ES');
```

But, I need the app to be translated dynamically, in an action listener button for example.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
I18n::locale('en_EN');
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847597/cakephp-3-0-0-rc2-i18nlocale-doesnt-works

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. Please be specific as to what exactly happens in which situation exactly, and add appropriate code context.

Comment: The problem is that when I use `I18n::locale('en_EN');` on a Controller, only translates the locale in this controller and not in all the app. My idea is to put a button or link on the nav bar that let translate the locale when you push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the locale in the session so that it persists between page requests.

A possible approach:

```
class AppController extends Controller {    

    public function initialize() {

        if ($this->request->session()->check('Config.locale')) {    
            I18n::locale($this->request->session()->read('Config.locale'));
        }

        //rest of your init code
    }


    public function change_locale($locale){

        $this->request->session()->write('Config.locale', $locale);
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }    

}
```

Comment: I get this error when I put that code on my AppController: _Call to a member function check() on a non-object_

Comment: Fixed a typo. Please try it now.

Comment: It works but that solution gives me errors on a template where i'm using ajax to call controller action.. :(

Comment: If you change the language via ajax, you don't need to call `return $this->redirect($this->referer())`. Instead, force a page reload from within Javascript when the ajax call has been completed.